# Django 3.* Python 3.* - saving space in database approach

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

if I have a char field that store specific strings of type values i.e ("CAR" or "MICROBUS" or "MINIBUS" or "BUS"), If I used binary instead of string i.e. ( `00` instead of "CAR", `01` instead of "MICROBUS", `10` instead of "MINIBUS" and `11` instead of "BUS") that would save a lot of space!

1. how to implement that approach in my models?
2. how to retrieve and deal with field data in my views? define constants or what?
3. is this approach a good practice or not? and why?

waiting your precious and expert opinions! have a nice day!

Comment: Are you really running out of space in the database or is this just for fun? It doesn't seem like a good thing to spend time optimising.

Comment: actually I found approach ! 
`field_name = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=((1, "SMALL"),(2, "LARGE"),)`

Comment: That's nice and all but remember that nobody looking at the database (rather than the code) will have any idea what it means.

Comment: nice point of view